# How can I replace the fill.oval with an image in this code?

Tags: java

I've been studying this code for hours but I can't seem to find a way. I'm really confused with this code. I want to replace the circles with an image. Is there a way to do it or none? I tried to do the draw(image); but it doesn't work.

```
import java.awt.*; //for Graphics
    import java.awt.event.*; //for KeyListener
    import javax.swing.*; //for JFrame

    public class MovingBallTester
    {
        //Declare private variables
        private final int UPGAP_Y, LOWGAP_Y;
        private MovingBallPanel mbp;
        private JFrame movingBallFrame;


//Constructor
public MovingBallTester()
{
    //Initialize private variables
    LOWGAP_Y = 270;
    UPGAP_Y = 210;
    mbp = new MovingBallPanel(LOWGAP_Y, UPGAP_Y);
    movingBallFrame = new JFrame("Moving Ball");

    //Set up the Basics of the Frame
    movingBallFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    movingBallFrame.addKeyListener(new KeypadListener());
    movingBallFrame.setResizable(false);

    //Add the MovingBallPanel to the Frame
    movingBallFrame.getContentPane().add(mbp);

    //Display the frame so the user can see it
    displayFrame();

    //Run the game
    runGame();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
//                  Methods called in the constructor
//--------------------------------------------------------

//Displays the frame so the user can see it
public void displayFrame()
{
    movingBallFrame.pack();
    movingBallFrame.show();
}

//Runs the game
public void runGame()
{
    //show "Loading"
    sleep(500);
    mbp.beginGame1();
    sleep(300);

    //show "Loading."
    mbp.beginGame2();
    sleep(300);

    //show "Loading.."
    mbp.beginGame3();
    sleep(300);

    //show "Loading..."
    mbp.beginGame4();
    sleep(300);

    //repeat process two more times
    mbp.beginGame1();
    sleep(300);
    mbp.beginGame2();
    sleep(300);
    mbp.beginGame3();
    sleep(300);
    mbp.beginGame4();
    sleep(300);
    mbp.beginGame1();
    sleep(300);
    mbp.beginGame2();
    sleep(300);
    mbp.beginGame3();
    sleep(300);
    mbp.beginGame4();
    sleep(300);

    //The game runs until the user exits
    while(true)
    {
        //The y value of the upper and lower
        //parts of the middle bar gap
        int lowerY = mbp.getLowerY();
        int upperY = mbp.getUpperY();

        //Move the balls
        mbp.callMoveBallMethod(lowerY,upperY);

        //Are the blue balls on the right and
        //are the yellow balls on the left?
        if(mbp.checkBalls())
        {
            //If so, restart with an extra ball
            mbp.addAnotherBall();
        }
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
//                          Sleep method
//--------------------------------------------------------

//Stalls the program so that program slows down
public void sleep(int i)
{
    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(i); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
//                      Key Listener Class
//--------------------------------------------------------

//This is just a private class that takes care of user keypad
//motion; specifically, up and down to move the middle bar
private class KeypadListener implements KeyListener
{
    //When the user presses up or down, this method is called
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        //Figure out if the user pressed up or down
        int source = e.getKeyCode();

        //If the user pressed up
        if(source == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            //Move the gap up
            mbp.moveGapLocationUp();

        }
        //If the user pressed down
        else if(source == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            //Move the gap down
            mbp.moveGapLocationDown();
        }
    }

    //Methods that need to be implemented
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
//                          Main method
//--------------------------------------------------------

//Just call the constructor, which will then call runGame
//and make the game run
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    new MovingBallTester();
}}
```

Class

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class MovingBallPanel extends JPanel
    {   
        //--------------------------------------------------------
        //                  Declare private variables
        //--------------------------------------------------------

        //This is the arraylist of balls
        private ArrayList<MovingBall> mb;

        //This is the arraylist of the balls in 
        //their original location. Througout the
        //program, the positions of the balls in
        //the mb array list change. However, the
        //initials arraylist is just the initial
        //positions of the balls, so that when an
        //extra ball is added, the original balls
        //can start over in their initial spots
        private ArrayList<MovingBall> initials; 

//The y values of the upper gap and lower gap
private int gapLY, gapTY;

//A variable representing the level the user is on
private int level;

//Width and Height
private final int APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT;


//--------------------------------------------------------
//                      Constructor
//--------------------------------------------------------

public MovingBallPanel(int lowerGapY, int topGapY)
{
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    //                Initialize private variables
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    //The array lists of balls
    mb = new ArrayList<MovingBall>();
    initials = new ArrayList<MovingBall>();

    //The upper and lower y values of the gap
    gapLY = lowerGapY;
    gapTY = topGapY;

    //The game starts on level 1
    level = 1;

    //The applet is 640 x 480
    APPLET_WIDTH = 640;
    APPLET_HEIGHT = 480;

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    //               Set up the BASICS of the panel
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    //The panel has dimensions of 640 width and 480 height
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT));

    //Set the background to be black
    setBackground(Color.black);

    //Declare mb to start out with 4 pre-defined balls
    //SEE MOVING BALL CLASS FOR EXPLANATION OF PARAMETERS
    mb.add(new MovingBall(20, 20, 136, 39,  131, 34,  APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT, Color.cyan));
    mb.add(new MovingBall(20, 20, 200, 200, 205, 195, APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT, Color.cyan));
    mb.add(new MovingBall(20, 20, 453, 282, 448, 277, APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT, Color.yellow));
    mb.add(new MovingBall(20, 20, 97,  365, 92,  360, APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT, Color.yellow));

    //Add those same balls to the initials array
    //SEE MOVING BALL CLASS FOR EXPLANATION OF PARAMETERS
    initials.add(new MovingBall(20, 20, 136, 39, 131,  34,  APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT, Color.cyan));
    initials.add(new MovingBall(20, 20, 200, 200, 205, 195, APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT, Color.cyan));
    initials.add(new MovingBall(20, 20, 453, 282, 448, 277, APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT, Color.yellow));
    initials.add(new MovingBall(20, 20, 97,  365, 92,  360, APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT, Color.yellow));
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
//                          Graphics methods
//--------------------------------------------------------

//This method is called initially and is 
//periodically called automatically
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    //paint background
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0,0,640,480);

    //paint middle white bar
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(315,0,10,gapTY);
    g.fillRect(315,gapLY,10,(480-gapLY));

    //put "blue" on the left
    //and "yellow" on the right
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.drawString("Blue", 145,20);
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.drawString("Yellow", 475,20); 

    //draw directions
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.drawString("Directions", 541, 410);
    g.drawString("1.Use the up and down", 500,430);
    g.drawString("arrows to move", 510,442);
    g.drawString("2.Get the balls on their", 500, 457);
    g.drawString("proper sides", 510, 470);

    //draw level
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.drawString(("Level: " + level), 8, 472);

    //paint balls
    for(int x = 0; x < mb.size(); x++)
    {
        MovingBall t = mb.get(x);
        g.setColor(t.getBallColor());
        g.fillOval(t.getCX(), t.getCY(), t.getBallSizeX(),t.getBallSizeY());
    }   
}

//Draws "Loading"
public void beginGame1()
{
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(186,157,14,5);
    g.fillRect(520,157,14,5);
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.drawString("Loading", 145,160);
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.drawString("Loading", 475,160);
}

//Draws "Loading."
public void beginGame2()
{
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(186,157,14,5);
    g.fillRect(520,157,14,5);
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.drawString("Loading.", 145,160);
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.drawString("Loading.", 475,160);
}

//Draws "Loading.."
public void beginGame3()
{
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(186,157,14,5);
    g.fillRect(520,157,14,5);
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.drawString("Loading..", 145,160);
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.drawString("Loading..", 475,160);
}

//Draws "Loading..."
public void beginGame4()
{
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(186,157,14,5);
    g.fillRect(520,157,14,5);
    g.setColor(Color.cyan);
    g.drawString("Loading...", 145,160);
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.drawString("Loading...", 475,160);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
//                          Getter methods
//--------------------------------------------------------

//returns the y value for the lower gap
public int getLowerY()
{
    return gapLY;
}

//returns the y value for the upper gap
public int getUpperY()
{
    return gapTY;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
//                          Moving The Balls
//--------------------------------------------------------

//This method goes through each individual ball
//and updates its position by calling the moveBall()
//method in the MovingBall class
public void callMoveBallMethod(int l, int u)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < mb.size(); x++)
    {
        //get the current ball
        MovingBall t = mb.get(x);

        //update its position
        t.moveBall(l,u);

        //now draw the new ball's position
        repaint();

    }

    //stall the program so the ball is not too fast
    sleep(20);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
//                          Advancing levels
//--------------------------------------------------------

//This method determines whether or not the
//blue balls are on the left side and the
//yellow balls are on the right side
public boolean checkBalls()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < mb.size(); x++)
    {
        //get the current ball
        MovingBall temp = mb.get(x);

        //get its color
        Color c = temp.getBallColor();

        //get its current x position
        int currentXPosition = temp.getCX();

        //if it's blue, make sure it is on the left
        if(c == Color.cyan)
        {
            if( !(currentXPosition<315) )
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        //if it's yellow, make sure it is on the right
        else
        {
            if( !(currentXPosition>325) )
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//If the checkBalls() method returns true, it means
//that the user is ready to advance to the next level.
//So this method is used to add another ball to the game randomly
public void addAnotherBall()
{
    //Make a random object used throughout this method
    Random rm = new Random();

    //Get random x and y values representing the 
    //current x and current y position of the new ball
    int cxValue = rm.nextInt(550) + 25;
    int cyValue = rm.nextInt(435) + 25;

    //xValue and yValue are numbers used to determine
    //the previous x and y positioin of the new ball
    //Set it to a default of -1 so the compiler does
    //not produce a "variable not initialized" error
    int xValue = -1;
    int yValue = -1;

    //get a number between 1 and 4 representing
    //the four possible ways for the ball to travel
    int n = rm.nextInt(4) + 1;

    //depending on the random number 1-4, initialize
    //xValue and yValue 
    if(n == 1)
    {
        xValue = 5;
        yValue = 5;
    }
    else if(n == 2)
    {
        xValue = 5;
        yValue = -5;
    }
    else if(n == 3)
    {
        xValue = -5;
        yValue = 5;
    }
    else if(n == 4)
    {
        xValue = -5;
        yValue = -5;
    }

    //get a random number to determine the color
    //of the new ball
    int k = rm.nextInt(2) + 1;

    //if k is 1, then the ball is cyan
    //if k is 2, then the ball is yellow
    Color g = Color.cyan;
    if(k == 2)
    {
        g = Color.yellow;
    }

    //now create the new ball
    initials.add(new MovingBall(20, 20, cxValue, cyValue, (cxValue+xValue), (cyValue+yValue), APPLET_WIDTH, APPLET_HEIGHT, g));

    //clear all the current balls so that the level can start over
    mb.clear();

    //now reset mb using the initials array with the 
    //inital positions of all the balls
    for(int y = 0; y < initials.size(); y++)
    {
        mb.add(initials.get(y));
    }

    //increaes the level
    level++;

    //if this new ball that was added makes that level win,
    //then that will be pointless, because the user won't 
    //have to do anything to advance to the next level.
    //So if this happens, this loop will get rid of the ball
    //that was just added, and try it again, until a ball is added
    //that does not make the level advance automatically
    if(checkBalls())
    {
        level--;
        initials.remove(initials.size()-1);
        addAnotherBall();
    }

    //while the program is cointinuing until it creates
    //a random ball that doesn't automatically make the 
    //level advance, it will cycle through the "Loading"
    //two times
    beginGame1();
    sleep(300);
    beginGame2();
    sleep(300);
    beginGame3();
    sleep(300);
    beginGame4();
    sleep(300);
    beginGame1();
    sleep(300);
    beginGame2();
    sleep(300);
    beginGame3();
    sleep(300);
    beginGame4();
    sleep(300);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
//                      Responding to input
//--------------------------------------------------------

//If the user presses "up" on the keyboard,
//then the gap is moved up
public void moveGapLocationUp()
{
    gapLY-=10;
    gapTY-=10;

}

//If the user presses "down" on the keyboard,
//then the gap is moved down.
public void moveGapLocationDown()
{
    gapLY+=10;
    gapTY+=10;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
//                          Sleep method
//--------------------------------------------------------

//Stalls the program so that program slows down
public void sleep(int i)
{
    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep (i); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

}

```
import java.awt.*; //for Color

public class MovingBall
{
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    //                  Declare private variables
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    //The size of the ball - x and y
    private int ballSizeX, ballSizeY;

    //The current position of the ball - x and y
    private int ballCX, ballCY;

    //The previous position of the ball - x and y
    private int ballPX, ballPY;

    //The applet dimensions - x and y
    private int maxX, maxY;

    //The ball's color
    Color color;

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    //                      Constructor
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    public MovingBall(int xsize, int ysize, int cX, int cY, int pX, int pY, int windowSizeX, int windowSizeY, Color c)
    {
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    //                Initialize private variables
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    ballSizeX = xsize; //the size of the ball - width
    ballSizeY = ysize; //the size of the ball - height

    ballCX = cX; //the current position - x value
    ballCY = cY; //the current position - y value

    ballPX = pX; //the previous position - x value
    ballPY = pY; //the previous position - y value

    maxX = windowSizeX; //the size of the screen - x value
    maxY = windowSizeY; //the size of the screen - y value

    color = c; //the color of the ball
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
//                         Getter methods
//--------------------------------------------------------

//---------------
// Ball Size
//---------------

public int getBallSizeX()
{
    return ballSizeX;
}

public int getBallSizeY()
{
    return ballSizeY;
}

//------------------
// Current positions
//------------------

public int getCX()
{
    return ballCX;
}

public int getCY()
{
    return ballCY;
}

//-------------------
// Previous positions
//-------------------

public int getPX()
{
    return ballPX;
}

public int getPY()
{
    return ballPY;
}

//---------------
// Ball Color
//---------------

public Color getBallColor()
{
    return color;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
//                         Setter methods
//--------------------------------------------------------

//------------------
// Current positions
//------------------

public void setCX(int i)
{
    ballCX = i;
}

public void setCY(int i)
{
    ballCY = i;
}

//-------------------
// Previous positions
//-------------------

public void setPX(int i)
{
    ballPX = i;
}

public void setPY(int i)
{
    ballPY = i;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
//                         Move the Ball
//--------------------------------------------------------

//This method updates the position of the ball based on its
//current position and previous position. The paramaters are
//the lowerY and the upperY for the gap in the middle of the game
//so that the ball knows to bounce off that bar, but not if 
//is at the position where the gap is. In that case, it goes
//through the gap.
public void moveBall(int lowY, int upY)
{
    //Just making new variables with shorter names
    int cx = getCX();
    int cy = getCY();
    int px = getPX();
    int py = getPY();

    //These values represent the change that will be made
    //to the ball. There are four possible directions 
    //the ball can go. These variables are used to determine
    //that direction
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    //                        Middle Bar Corners
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    //if the ball hits the top left corner of the middle bar
    if( (cx>=325) && (cx<=330) && (cy<=5) && (cy<=upY || cy>=lowY) )
    {
        x = 5;
        y = 5;
        cx = 327;
        cy = 2;
    }

    //if the ball hits the bottom left corner of the middle bar
    else if( (cx>=325) && (cx<=330) && (cy>=475-ballSizeY) && (cy<=upY || cy>=lowY) )
    {
        x = 5;
        y = -5;
        cx = 327;
        cy = maxY-ballSizeY-2;
    }

    //if the ball hits the top right corner of the middle bar
    else if( (cx>=310-ballSizeX) && (cx<=315-ballSizeX) && (cy<=5) && (cy<=upY || cy>=lowY) )
    {
        x = -5;
        y = 5;
        cx = 310-ballSizeX-2;
        cy = 2;
    }

    //if the ball hits the bottom right corner of the middle bar
    else if( (cx>=310-ballSizeX) && (cx<=315-ballSizeX) && (cy>=475-ballSizeY) && (cy<=upY || cy>=lowY) )
    {
        x = -5;
        y = -5;
        cx = 315-ballSizeX-2;
        cy = maxY-ballSizeY-2;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    //                       Middle Bar Non Corners
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    //if the ball hits the left side of the middle bar, and it is going from [down right] to [down left]
    else if( ( (cx>=315-ballSizeX && cx<=325-ballSizeX) && (cy<=upY || cy>=lowY )) && (cx-px>=5) && (cy-py>=5) )
    {
        x-=5;
        y+=5;
    }

    //if the ball hits the left side of the middle bar, and it is giong from [up right] to [up left]
    else if( ( (cx>=315-ballSizeX && cx<=325-ballSizeX) && (cy<=upY || cy>=lowY ) ) && (cx-px>=5) && (py-cy>=5) ) 
    {
        x-=5;
        y-=5;
    }

    //if the ball hits the right side of the middle bar, and it is going from [down left] to [down right]
    else if( ( (cx>=315 && cx<=325) && (cy<=upY || cy>=lowY ) ) && (px-cx>=5) && (cy-py>=5) )
    {
        x+=5;
        y+=5;
    }

    //if the ball hits the right side of the middle bar, and it is going from [up left] to [up right]
    else if( ( (cx>=315 && cx<=325) && (cy<=upY || cy>=lowY ) ) && (px-cx>=5) && (py-cy>=5) )
    {
        x+=5;
        y-=5;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    //               Normal Motion -- Not hitting sides
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    //if the ball is moving [down right]
    else if( !(cy>=maxY-ballSizeY) && !(cx>=maxX-ballSizeX) && !(cy<=0) && !(cx<=0) && (cx>=5) && (cy>=5) && (cx-px>=5) && (cy-py>=5) )
    {
        x+=5;
        y+=5;
    }

    //if the ball is moving [up right]
    else if( !(cy>=maxY-ballSizeY) && !(cx>=maxX-ballSizeX) && !(cy<=0) && !(cx<=0) && (cx>=5)&& (cy>=5) && (cx-px>=5) && (py-cy>=5) )
    {
        x+=5;
        y-=5;
    }

    //if the ball is moving [down left]
    else if( !(cy>=maxY-ballSizeY) && !(cx>=maxX-ballSizeX) && !(cy<=0) && !(cx<=0) && (cx>=5)&& (cy>=5) && (px-cx>=5) && (cy-py>=5) )
    {
        x-=5;
        y+=5;
    }

    //if the ball is moving [up left]
    else if( !(cy>=maxY-ballSizeY) && !(cx>=maxX-ballSizeX) && !(cy<=0) && !(cx<=0) && (cx>=5)&& (cy>=5) && (px-cx>=5) && (py-cy>=5) )
    {
        x-=5;
        y-=5;       
    }   

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    //           Normal Corners -- Non Barrier Corners
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    //if the ball hits the top left corner
    else if( (cx<=4) && (cy<=4) ) 
    {
        x = 5;
        y = 5;
        cx = 2;
        cy = 2;
    }

    //if the ball hits the bottom left corner
    else if( (cx<=4) && (cy>=maxY-ballSizeY-4) )
    {
        x = 5;
        y = -5;
        cx = 2;
        cy = maxY-ballSizeY-2;
    }

    //if the ball hits the top right corner
    else if( (cy<=4) && (cx>=maxX-ballSizeX-4) )
    {
        x = -5;
        y = 5;
        cx = maxX-ballSizeX-2;
        cy = 2;
    }

    //if the ball hits the bottom right corner
    else if( (cy>=maxY-ballSizeY-4) && (cx>=maxX-ballSizeX-4) )
    {
        x = -5;
        y = -5;
        cx = maxX-ballSizeX-2;
        cy = maxY-ballSizeY-2;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    //           Normal Sides - Non Barrier Sides
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    //if the ball hits the bottom side and goes from [down right] to [up right]
    else if( (cy >= 480-ballSizeY) && (cx-px>= 5) && (cy-py>=5) )
    {   
        x+=5;
        y-=5;
    }

    //if the ball hits the bottom side and goes from [down left] to [up left]
    else if( (cy>=480-ballSizeY) && (px-cx>=5) && (cy-py>=5) )
    {
        x-=5;
        y-=5;
    }

    //if the ball hits the top side and goes from [up right] to [down right]
    else if( (cy <= 4) && (cx-px >=5) && (py-cy>=5) )
    {
        x+=5;
        y+=5;
    }

    //if the ball hits the top side and goes from [up left] to [down left]
    else if( (cy<=4) &&  (px-cx>=5) && (py-cy>=5) )
    {
        x-=5;
        y+=5;
    }

    //if the ball hits the right side and goes from [down right] to [down left]
    else if( (cx>=640-ballSizeX) &&  (cx-px>=5) && (cy-py>=5) )
    {
        x-=5;
        y+=5;
    }

    //if the ball hits the right side and goes from [up right] to [up left]
    else if( (cx>=640-ballSizeX) && (cx-px>=5) && (py-cy>=5) )
    {
        x-=5;
        y-=5;
    }

    //if the ball hits the left side and goes from [down left] to [down right]
    else if( (cx<=4)  && (px-cx>=5) && (cy-py>=5) )
    {   
        x+=5;
        y+=5;
    }

    //if the ball hits the left side and goes from [up left] to [up right]
    else if( (cx<=4) &&  (px-cx>=5) && (py-cy>=5) )
    {
        x+=5;
        y-=5;
    }

    //Now that we have determined what direction the ball should go
    //based on its current and previoud psotitions, we need to update
    //the current positions and previous positions. The NEW previous 
    //positions will be the OLD current positions
    setPX(cx);
    setPY(cy);
    setCX(cx+x);
    setCY(cy+y);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
//                          Sleep method
//--------------------------------------------------------

//Stalls the program so that program slows down

public void sleep(int i)
{
    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep (i); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

}

Comment: Create a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That's a lot of code you're showing, and I'm sure most of it is irrelevant to the issue. Developers will turn away from the question simply because they didn't want to read all the code. Check out [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: To increase chances of getting answers you should: (1) tag your question with technologies you are using so specialist observing these tags will see your question (so add `swing` tag) (2) post [short example which reproduces your problem](http://sscce.org/) instead of posting your entire code which in 90% it is not related to your problem. To update your question use [edit] option.